# Block access to robots.txt file .htaccess

Tags: htaccess, robots.txt, user-agent, http-code-500

I read in [this forum](http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum93/74.htm) that this .htaccess code should block access to the robot.txt file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Mozilla
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(Slurp|surfsafely)
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ /someotherfile [L]
```

But I just get a error 500: "Internal Server Error"

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have a file named "someotherfile" in your site's root (and also obviously a robots.txt file). Also the .htaccess should have `RewriteEngine On` somewhere above the block you posted.

Comment: Thank you soo much!! - I had the RewriteEngine On, but the problem was as you said that I haven't created a file named: "someotherfile" THANK YOU! :D